# Elimination of left recursion

Tags: grammar, left-recursion

I am trying to remove left recursion from following grammar:

```
S -> id = E
S -> id [ E ] = E
E -> E [ E ]
E -> id
```

I tried to follow the left recursion removal algorithm that is presented at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion, but the `E -> E [ E ]` line gives me problems, how should it be handled?
I do not want to get a complete solution to this, just some hints so I can actually learn how this works.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
E -> E [ E ]
E -> id
```

becomes:

```
E -> id E'
E' -> [ E ] E'
```

Which is incorrect. Am I even on the right track here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the algorithm you linked to, you want A -> Aα | β and you have

```
E -> E [ E ] | id
```

so A is `E`, α is `[ E ]` and β is `id`.  The result of removing left recursion is A -> β A' and A' -> ε | α A', so you get the rules:

```
E -> id E'
E' -> ε | [ E ] E'
```

So it looks like you got the right result, you just left out the E' -> ε rule...

Comment: Thank you. The epsilon rule was missing just like you said and that was the problem.